# Remove the same response objects from an array of response objects in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

If I have an array: `[response, response, response]` and at least two of them have a `response.code` of 500, how do I remove all but one of those response objects from the array?

So my resulting array should be `[response, response]`, this way there is only one response object with a `response.code` of 500 and one with a `response.code` of something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this:

```
[response, response, response].uniq(&:code)
```